# Summation involving binomial coefficient, exponent and another term

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am trying to find if a closed form formula exists for the following summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}\frac{x^{i}}{i+k}$$

where $x$ and $k$ can be any real numbers. I tried to search but the closest I found was the following identity (from vol.2 at https://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}\frac{x^{i}}{i+1}=\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)x}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} \frac{x^{i}}{i+k}$ has a closed-form evaluation whenever $k$ is a fixed natural number. For example, we have that $\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{i} x^i}{i+2} = \frac{n x^2 (x+1)^n+x^2 (x+1)^n+n x (x+1)^n-(x+1)^n+1}{(n+1) (n+2) x^2}$, and we have that $\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{\binom{n}{i} x^i}{i+3} = \frac{n^2 x^3 (x+1)^n+n^2 x^2 (x+1)^n+3 n x^3 (x+1)^n+2 x^3 (x+1)^n+n x^2 (x+1)^n-2 n x
   (x+1)^n+2 (x+1)^n-2}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3) x^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

A partial solution. Let $S$ be the desired sum. Then observe that for $k > 0$,
\begin{align*}
x^k\cdot S&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}\frac{x^{i+k}}{i+k}=
\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}\int_{0}^x t^{i+k-1}\,dt\\
&=\int_{0}^x \sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i} t^{i+k-1}
=\int_{0}^x t^{k-1}(1+t)^n\,dt.
\end{align*}
If $k\geq 1$ is a natural number, we can repeatedly integrate by parts to evaluate the last integral.

Comment: Is there an approximation for the last integral that you obtain if k is negative?